# Given a positive integer $N$ which for$N$ objects, add $m>0$ so N+m objects have a common factor. Find the minimum sum of all the numbers added.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We are provided with a positive number N which denotes that we have N objects. Each of those N objects hold a value.
Now we are provided a task to add non-negative value to the objects in such a way that the resultant values of N objects have a common factor .
Find the minimum sum of all the numbers added.

For example :-
Suppose N = 3
and we have objects with values as:-
11 ,21 ,24
The answer to this is 1 as we can add 1 to 11 , and thus resultant values become
12, 21, 24 ,
which have 3 as common factor .

Comment: I understand that you can add a number (same number) to all the objects that you want. In that case, if you have $N$ objects, all even, then sum 0. If this isn't the case, plus 1 to all the odd objects and then the resulting $N$ objects are all even. Could you be more clear?

Comment: The thing is not about odd or even . How can your technique work for the example i mentioned above?

Comment: Is the common factor specified?  If not, then the comment of @sinbadh seems to settle the matter.  In your example, add $1$ to $11,21$ to get the triple $12,22,24$ which share the factor $2$.  On its face, that would seem to pass your requirements...

Comment: @lulu but that would not be the minimum, the question clearly asks for minimum.

Comment: But minimum such value is required . Common factor is required , and min value is 1 , whereas as per the above mentioned procedure , answer is 2

Comment: $1$ isn't the minimum?  It's the same value you use.  Or are you saying that in this way we have added $1$ twice, for a total of $2$?

Comment: @lulu min answer is 1. The above mentioned approach gives 2

Comment: user249117. I repeat to you: I'm understanding that you can add \emph{the same} number to all the objects that you want. Then, if all the objects are even, add 0 to the first of them (the common factor is trivially 2). If there are odd objects, to this ones add 1. In your example, adding 1 to 11 and 21 we get (12, 22, 24), with common factor 2.

Comment: it is not mandatory to add same number to all objects

Comment: @sinbadh  I agree this isn't clear.  I believe that what the OP means is that we are to minimize the total value added.  Your method adds a total of $2$ to the sum (in the example), hence is not as good as adding $1$.

Comment: @lulu I agree with you.

Comment: I doubt there is a simple closed formula here.  Simple programming matter.  . The even/odd method gives you an easy upper bound on the answer.  Now you can try $p=3$.  work out the value in that case.  Then $p=5$.  At some point, the minimal term in the sum will need a summand higher than the upper bound, so you can stop.

Comment: @lulu can you pls explain through some example your approach?

Comment: I'll write one up and post it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking the problem as a programming question will make it easy.

For given $N$ objects $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n\}$, find all values of primes $p$, such that there exist a value of $i$, such that $x_i \mod p =0 $.

For all such values of $p$ find the minimum value to be added to $x_i$, such that $x_i \mod p =0 $ if $x_i \mod p \ne 0 $. This value is equal to $p - (x_i \mod p) $.

For all values of p, find the sum of all the values added to $x_i$, the minimum among them will be the answer.

Comment: Thanx a lot . This was the exact approach i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Don't see a simple closed formula.  As a programming method, note that the even/odd calculation gives an upper bound (equal to the number of odd numbers in the list).  Then work prime by prime until the least element needs too great a summand.

Example (randomly chosen):  $$L=\{12,17,23,31,43,57,91,102\}$$

There are $6$ odd numbers in the list so the upper bound is $6$.

Now try $p=3$ working mod$3$ we get $$L\equiv \{0,2,2,1,1,0,1,0\}$$.  Thus we must add $\{0,1,1,2,2,0,2,0\}$ which sums to a value greater than $6$.

Now try $p=5$. working mod$5$ we get  $$L\equiv \{2,2,3,1,3,2,1,2\}$$ and again it is no good.

Similarly, we can rule out $p=\{7,11,13,17\}$.  No need to look any further as we
we'd clearly have to add more than $6$ to $12$.  Hence the upper bound was good, and the answer is $6$.

Comment: Thanx a lot . That helped a lot :)