# Minimum sum of the numbers added to elements of a set to meet the condition(mentioned below)?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

**Problem Statement** :

> We have to add different numbers(could be 0 too) to elements of a set so that gcd of all elements becomes greater than 1 and the set is arranged in ascending order.
>
> Example : Set S = {5,4,7,6,8}
>
> Now the best alteration to fit the above condition will lead to => {6,6,8,8,8}
>
> So the answer will be 1+2+1+2+0 = 6

**Till now I've done this :**

1. Change the elements such that the set becomes sorted.

   A0<=A1<=A2<=A3<=...<=An
2. Now if the set contains two or more distinct primes, increment all of them by 1.
3. Now, I thought seeing that if there are more even numbers than odd, then least sum would be equal to number of odd elements(each incremented by 1).

   But I was wrong as : if S = {5,10,15,20,24} answer would be 1 (changing 24 to 25).

How should I tackle this problem ?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It is very similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595964/procedure-to-solve-this-number-theory-question?noredirect=1#comment3250503_1595964 .  Is this part of programming competition?

Comment: Damn. I searched a lot for it. But couldn't find it. I'm having trouble using stack exchange. Can you help me ?

Comment: I don't want to interfere with a live competition and when variants of an algorithm question start showing up at the same time, that's usually the source.  Where does this problem come from?